# Is it possible to use __init__ values from a class calling another class?

Tags: python, class, import

So I have two class that are called:

a.py

```
import requests

class A:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.accessToken = "VeryImportant" <---

    def productFeed(self, Country, UserInput):

        while True:
            try:

                else:
                    params = {
                        'country': UserInput,
                        'locale': 'en-{}_{}'.format(UserInput, UserInput)
                    }

                headers = {
                    'importante': 'Yessir {}'.format(self.accessToken),

                }
                r = requests.get("URL", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=5)

                # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    return r.json()
```

b.py

```
import lib.vendors.testing.a as testing

class B:

    def __init__(self):
        self.getClassA = testing.A

    def main(self):

        country = "GB"
        UserInput = "Hello"

        print(self.getClassA.productFeed(country, UserInput))
```

However it seems like I am getting issue on class A: saying `TypeError: ProductFeed() missing 1 required positional argument: 'UserInput'`

The issue I believe is related to the `self` - I assume I need to add it into the params inside the `self.getClassA.productFeed(country, UserInput)` however the issue will be that if I send over the self, it doesn't want to use the self.accessToken from class A in that case and then I am not able to the the correct request.

What I want to do is that if I call `self.getClassA.productFeed(country, UserInput)`- I want to use the self.accessToken that is in class A instead of needing to send it over

What should I do to be able to do that?

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis in the last line (```print```).

Comment: What is `testing.A`? Is it the reference to the class? Or an instance of the class?

Comment: instance of the class @rdas :)

Comment: How was `testing.A` created? Show the complete code

Comment: import lib.vendors.testing.a as testing -> self.getClassA = testing.A -> self.getClassA.productFeed(country, UserInput) -> CLASS A: def productFeed(self, Country, UserInput): - @rdas or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like you're actually importing `A` and then calling it *as a class*. I don't see where you've created an *instance* - and since `productFeed()` is an instance method, it expects to be called on an instance, not on the class itself.

Comment: You don't have an instance of the class but the reference to the class itself. That's why it's asking for an argument (missing self). If you had an instance of the class, then that instance itself would be `self`

Comment: Ohhh my bad, I mean the code you see is what I am currently having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose to use something as static.
If "accessToken" isn't different for every instance of the class A you can define it before the **init** function. In that way you can read it by using A.accessToken and your program wont crash anymore.
However if accessToken is static, this means that different instances of the class A cannot have different values for accessToken.

You can make the productFeed function static and change the self with anything else. When you call it you have to pass an instance of A as argument

In A class

```
@staticmethod
def productFeed(instance, Country, UserInput):

    while True:
        try:
            else:
            params = {
                'country': UserInput,
                'locale': 'en-{}_{}'.format(UserInput, UserInput)
            }

        headers = {
            'importante': 'Yessir {}'.format(instance.accessToken),

        }
        r = requests.get("URL", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=5)

        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return r.json()
```

in main

```
def main(self):

    country = "GB"
    UserInput = "Hello"

    print(self.getClassA.productFeed(A(None),country, UserInput))
```

Comment: Oh right, however the access.token might be changed of course so I would say it is needed to have it and it is not static but is different for each instance

Comment: With the second method (the one with the code) every instance can have a different value for AccessToken and you have to use it with an object (not directly with the class).

    a_obj = A()
    print(a_obj.accessToken)

this will work

but not this 

 A.accessToken

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating an instance of the A class. You use a direct reference:

```py
testing.A
```

where you should use

```py
testing.A( ... )
```

Your code is interpreting the `country` variable as the self argument because self is not a keyword